# javascript says $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a specific div on my page reload every 30 seconds.

So I found:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

at apt.jquery.com,
I tried to use it as:

```
setInterval(function(){
        $('#floormap_display').load(document.URL +  '#floormap_display');
    },30000);
```

and as:

```
setInterval(function(){
        jQuery.ajax('#floormap_display').load(document.URL +  '#floormap_display');
    },30000);
```

Either way I get an error, the error is either

> TypeError: $ is not a function

or

> TypeError: jQuery.ajax(...).load is not a function

I'm assuming this is because I'm trying to use jQuery in the middle of some javascript, I just can't find information on the issue anywhere or the correct way to do it.

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library in your page?

Comment: yes, I'm using things like jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'floormap_callback',
   data: {'floormap_delete':floormap},
   success: function(data){
    window.location.reload();
   }
  });   elsewhere in the page with no issue.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted that last comment.  I do not have this inside a $(document).ready()

Comment: These two error messages are not triggered by the same error. When the message is "`$` is not a function", it means `$` exists, but it's not a function, hence `$` has been overridden with another value. In the second case `#floormap_display` doesn't exist. It seems, that you've somehow overridden `$` before executing this paticular snippet.

Answer (score 2):

```
//you can be safe if theres jquery by checking for it
if(window.jQuery){
  console.log('jquery is loaded');
  //to be save with $ use this syntax of ready function
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );   
  });
}else {
  console.log('jquery is not loaded')
}


// very important is that you include jquery _before_ any single line of "your" jquery-code
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are not loading the jQuery library or you are calling this code before the jQuery library has been loaded. Be sure that you have included the jquery library BEFORE calling any code (it is best to include it in the ).

Answer (score 0):

Check the srcipt-tags in the page header, fisrt of all you have to proof if the jquery-library is referenced correctly.